# Alternative to strcpy? or fix to strcpy in program?

Tags: c, string, stdio, strcpy, strncpy

I can't figure out what is wrong with this program. I have tried using

```
                      strncpy(text,array[ ],sizeof(text))
```

already but that didn't solve anything. What I need is a simple method of copying string like in pascal language, where a simple equal sign can be used to copy string (or a generated function that can do this). this is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int x,y;

char array[10][10];
int choice;
char text[5];


int main()
 {
    for(x=0;x<5;x++)
     {
        printf("ENTER text: ");
        scanf("%s", text);   
        strcpy (text,array[x]);
     }

     for (y=0;y<5;y++)
      {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s", array[y]);
      }
    return 0;
 }
```

the output should be something like;

```
"*string*"
"*string*"
"*string*"
"*string*"
"*string*"
```

but all i get is five spaces, no string. Any Solutions?

Comment: `strcpy (text,array[x]);` --> `strcpy (array[x], text);`

Comment: it's `strcpy(destination, source)`, you're doing it backwards, so you're copying an empty array into `text`

Comment: ok simple mistake, thanks but the real question is is any alternative to strcpy?

Comment: *"the real question is is any alternative to strcpy"* isn't that an X-Y  question? The real problem is that you were not using `strcpy` correctly. Why re-invent library functions that work perfectly well (once you know how)?

Comment: I am curious why one thinks `"*string*"` will fit in a `char text[5];` when using `scanf("%s", text);`?

Comment: there were some some cases i have encountered before where strcmp wasn't working correctly, the program crashes so i was wondering if there was any alternative to it @Vane

Comment: the asterisks and quotes aren't included. @chux

Comment: 1) `string` will not fit in `char text[5];`: no room for the null character.   2) since  asterisks and quotes aren't included, posting them as part of expected output confuses this post's goal.  3) So what is the input tried - exactly?

Comment: the string shown is only a place holder for the actual string which has a strlen of < 6 and input would be something random like pp,nn,mm,ll,aa, as long as it shows in the order that is shown in the coding and yea ur right about the asterisk confusing the post

Comment: In an 5 element long char array, you can only fit strings which have an strlen() result less or equal to 4 (don't forget the terminating null character!). It is not strcmp() etc. not working correctly, rather a characteristic of the C language. It is not possible to figure out the length of a storage a pointer is pointing at (and those functions only "see" the pointers), so you have to add any necessary protection against such yourself.

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
strcpy (text,array[x]);
```

is invalid. I think you mean

```
strcpy( array[x], text );
```

Take into account that you should write

```
scanf("%4s", text); 
       ^^^^
```

Comment: ok thanks for the fix but do you know of any alternative to strcpy?

Comment: @Questionare232 No, I do not know. Of course you can use such string functions like strncpy or memcpy but they differ from strcpy in the used logic. In C arrays do not have the assignment operator. You have to copy arrays element by element.

Comment: @Questionare232 You can enclose an array in a structure and in this case you can assign one object of the structure to another object in fact assigning the enclosed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy (text,array[x]);
```

Instead of this ,you should try this -

```
strcpy (array[x],text);
```

First argument of `strcpy` is the destination and second is source.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameters to `strcpy` in the wrong order.

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy:

> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

dest means destination, src means source.